# How to add hyperlink to bibliography titles in Jekyll using Jekyll-pandoc and jekyll-scholar bibtex renders?

Tags: hyperlink, jekyll, pandoc, bibtex, csl

I am using Jekyll with pandoc and Jekyll-scholar plugins to render bibtex database to appear on my static website. I wonder if there is any easy way to automatically add hyperlinks to all article titles of the rendered bibliography? I have tried to modify some CSL bibtex style template, but it doesn't seem to support hyperlink. I don't have any clue on how to using other methods to make it work.

A page I am working on can be found at http://i2000s.github.io/pubs/. The source code can be found at http://github.com/i2000s/i2000s.github.io/ (the Vita.html file). The configuration of Jekyll-scholar plugin can be found in the `_config.yml` file with more detailed information of the CSL style and bibtex files I am using. Thanks!

Comment: If CSL doesn't support hyperlinks, you'll have to write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html)...

Comment: @mb21 Thank you for the link. It seems, following this method, I need to compile the markdown to html and then filter out entries with urls and then add the urls to titles. The difficulty is that, in html, those titles could be repeating and don't have unique id or class denoted, and it might be hard to find where to put those links... I will double check it later.

Comment: If I add a _html={linkt_to_pub.html}_ tag to the publication within the .bib file, a link button is created automatically.